# How to track employees entering into the office?

Tags: smartcard, id-card

I need to track when employees enter the office.

What sensors should I buy? What ID card should I use? I am planning to use java. Will the card providers provide any API for that?

Comment: You'll have to ask your card and sensor providers.

Comment: When I worked on an implementation of a similar system like 15 years ago, we used simple barcode cards. These are damn cheap to produce (we used an office laser printer and a laminating machine), have simple sensors and work well in harsh environments (it was a power plant). Today we'd probably use a QR or other 2D code that carries more info, and a simple reader. The downside is, of course, that such a card is easy to copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best use RF tagged ID cards. Touchless & easy to use. There are also some very good RF tag libraries out there with support for many RF tag providers (better search the java libs first and then decide on the vendor). You will definitely need RF doors (just like in public libraries) or mini RF sensors.